# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null at

Tags: javascript

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
>       at script.js:1

```
var muneItem= document.getElementById("Menu").getElementsByTagName("li");
```

Comment: Is this a c# question? it looks like javascript syntax.

Comment: Apparently there is not an element with the id `Menu` in your document.

Comment: Please post your code. It appears the issue is not with the line you have shown us, but with either a spelling/capitalization mistake on an ID attribute, or some other such error.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure there is an element with the id "Menu" in your HTML.